# Remove previous view controllers from view hierarchy after update from background

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I want to remove previous view controllers from view hierarchy after update my app from background. To achieve this, I set background fetch completion handler.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  
  UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(1200)
  return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // reload occur
        reloadApp()
        completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

For reloading, I `instantiate` ViewController from StoryBoard.

```
func reloadApp() {

   // previous ViewController Stack has not been removed.

   let rootStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let rootVC = rootStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController")
    rootVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootVC
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

This approach reloads new ViewController correctly. But, I still have previous view controllers. Below image shows my situation.

[image]

Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Cant you just call popToRootViewController on the main navigation controller?

Comment: @Scriptable How can I access main navigation controller in that situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if let therootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    // If rootViewcontroller is navigationController then pop to root if any controllers has been pushed, dismiss if any controllers has been presented.
}
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nil
let rootStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootVC = rootStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController")
rootVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootVC
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: How can I remove whole controllers? If I just `if let therootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            if let navCon = therootController as? UINavigationController {
                navCon.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
            } else {
                therootController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }` call like this, it cannot dismiss whole controllers, if previous controller has modal Controller.

Comment: for controller in navCon.viewControllers {
                    //dismiss or pop all the controllers here
                }

Comment: This does not remove the previous view, simply doesn't work.